# Query parameter incorrectly matches route values .net 4.8

Tags: c#, routes

I have a route in Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.7 which incorrectly matches a query parameter with a route value.

My controller and action is:

```
    [RoutePrefix("v0/departments/{projectId}")]
    [Resource("Collections")]
    public class ExampleController : V0BaseContentController
    {  

        [Route("collections/{identifier}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> QueryCollection(int projectId, string identifier)
        {
            var result = Request.RequestUri.Query;

            return await Run(projectId, (p, v) => QueryInternal(p, v, identifier, LangCode));
        }
```

When my query parameter (?id=1234) doesn't match the name of the route it works as expected:

`http://localhost:5171/v0/departments/66/collections/projects?id=1234`

In this case the values in my controller action are as follows:

```
projectId = 66
identifier = "projects"
Request.RequestUri.Query = "?id=1234"
```

[Correctly routed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQYP0.png)

If my query parameter has the name matching the route value of 'identifier' this matches the /{identifier} route. IE:

```
http://localhost:5171/v0/departments/66/collections/projects?identifier=1234
```

In this case the values in my controller action are as follows:

```
projectId = 66
identifier = 1234
Request.RequestUri.Query = "?identifier=1234"
```

In this instance how do I make sure the identifier route value is set to the value of 'projects' ?

[Incorrectly matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRuoX.png)

Comment: use [FromRoute] in the identifier parameter. Something like this [FromRoute] string identifier. If you want specific values from queryString use [FromQuery] in the parameters.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are putting `{identifier}` in your route? You can change to something more specific to avoid this scenario.

Comment: Thanks @SharathNS [FromRoute] doesn't appear as an attribute in System.Web.Http.Routing. It wants me to install aspnetcore.mvc, if I install and try use this I still get the same behaviour.